# Data rescue mission: Ubuntu, Wubi, and Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, wubi

While working in my Ubuntu partition (set up via magic when I double-clicked a wubi.exe six months ago), I was uncareful and filled up my hard drive while trying to install some package I don't even remember. Now, I'm getting the "GNOME Power Manager error", described [here.](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1727071.html)

I've come up with two ways of solving my problem, neither of which are working.

1) **Boot from an Ubuntu Live CD, delete some files.** This would be fine, except that when I changed my Lenovo Ideapad's BIOS to have IDE CE *japanese name, numbers* and USB CD at the top, it still ignores the Ubuntu CD and proceeds to ask me to choose between Windows and the broken Ubuntu.

2) **Rescue the data, reinstall via wubi.** It took me a long time of poking around in Windows to discover that there's a C:\ubuntu\disks directory with directory "boot" and files "root.disk" and "swap.disk". Naively, I'm considering copying "root.disk" somewhere, reinstalling, and putting that file where I originally took it from. I don't know how dumb an idea this is.

3) **Something more clever.**

Usually I limit myself to making my .vimrc really pretty; this is more a more serious problem than I'm used to, and while I have my absolutely vital data backed up, I'd like to minimize what I lose.

**UPDATE**
I couldn't confirm that it was a working Live CD as I had no other computer with a CD drive handy. So, I've made a USB stick of Ubuntu 11.04 (note: I was running 10.04 before, in case that could make something go wrong), and booted successfully from that.

df -h gets me

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
aufs                  1.9G   46M  1.8G   3% /
none                  1.9G  696K  1.9G   1% /dev
/dev/sdb              981M  698M  283M  72% /cdrom
/dev/loop0            665M  665M     0 100% /rofs
none                  1.9G  188K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 1.9G   20K  1.9G   1% /tmp
none                  1.9G   92K  1.9G   1% /var/run
none                  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /var/lock
/dev/sr0              688M  688M     0 100% /media/Ubuntu 10.04
```

I imagine it's the 100%'s that are the problem. I'm supposed to mount(?) these, then? I don't quite understand what mount does.

Comment: Is the liveCD really a working LiveCD?  Does it work in other machines?  +1 because you mention backups.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, even though you have set the boot order of devices on your machine to be:

1. USB Devices
2. CD Drive
3. Hard Drive

You still end up booting from the hard drive?

If so, the solution that comes to mind if it is a desktop computer is to remove the hard drive, place it in an external enclosure. Then boot off a liveCD on your computer, and then hookup the external enclosure to the computer. You will then be able to edit the files that you need.

Answer (score 0):

er, no. rofs = read only file system - which is always 100% and refers to your livecd/non persistant part of the USB. You will need to [loopmount root.disk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount) from the livcd, tdo what you need to do, then boot back into your wubi system